# VB 2010 openfiledialog file format not valid

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, openfiledialog, rich-text-editor

I've been working on a text editor for a while now and nearing completion have finally decided to start looking at this issue the has bugged me for quite some time...

I have an openfiledialog that always gives me and error of "file format not valid"

```
Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim openWork As New OpenFileDialog
    openWork.Filter = "Text Documents (*.swtf)|*.swtf|Text Documents (*.rtf)|*.rtf|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    If openWork.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        RichTextBox1.LoadFile(openWork.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
        Title.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openWork.FileName)
    End If
End Sub
```

The error RichTextBox1.LoadFile(openWork.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText) comes up with no solutions but always gives me a "file format not valid" error - Including my custom file extension and the .rtf "rich text file" extension.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It works if the file you're opening is a true rich text file. If you try to load a file which isn't an .rtf, it will throw a **file format not valid** error because you're using `RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText` in the LoadFile method.

You can try something like this...I tested it in VB2010 and it works:

```
    Dim openWork As New OpenFileDialog
    openWork.Filter = "Text Documents (*.swtf)|*.swtf|Text Documents (*.rtf)|*.rtf|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    If openWork.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        'if the file is an .rtf, use the rich text format, if not, use plain text
        RichTextBox1.LoadFile(openWork.FileName, IIf(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(openWork.FileName) = ".rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText))
        Title.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openWork.FileName)
    End If
```

Comment: The only problem here is that now if I open a .swtf which is set as rtf file format it defaults to plain text and is unreadable giving the "file format not valid" error

Comment: actually it still gives me a file extension error for both file types, is there any way to force it to read no matter what? -I tried opening a .swtf before trying the rtf